# Iterate over json data updating a dictionary

Tags: jquery

Im trying to iterate over json data and assign it each key in the below dictionary

```
var tasks = { 
   data:[ 
     { 
       id:1,
       text:Label
     }
   ]
};
```

This how far I got:

labels:  ["A", "B", "C ", "D", "A", "B", "C ", "D"]

```
n = 0;
for (n in labels) {
    newlab = "label" + n;
    newid = "id" + n;
    var tasks = {
        data: [{
            id: newid,
            text: newlab
        },]
    };
};
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be something like below. as you are creating object and array inside a loop so it will not populate whole data it will populate only last record.

```js
var labels=["A", "B", "C ", "D", "A", "B", "C ", "D"]
var n = 0;var arr=[];
for (var i=0;i<labels.length;i++){
newlab = "label" + labels[i];
newid = "id" +labels[i]; 
arr.push({id:newid,text:newlab})
};
var tasks = { data:arr};
console.log(tasks);
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain what was wrong in OP's code and how you fixed it ? Thanks